# In multilingual countries like Canada, are the movies translated in every language?

Tags: distribution, translation

In multilingual countries like Canada, are the movies translated in every language? I'm talking about the title of the movie and the translation/subtitles with original language.

Comment: In Quebec ("French part" of the Canada), there is a law (http://legisquebec.gouv.qc.ca/fr/ShowDoc/cs/C-11) to promote French, so movie titles and other stuff have to be translated in French, whereas in France, we keep sometimes English title and their translation from Quebec seems weird.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Quebec, most films are shown in cinemas in both French and English. Originally French films may not be shown in English, though, and some Quebec cinemas are French-only. On the other hand, outside of Quebec most cinemas (in my experience) are English-only.

Movie titles are bilingual. DVD releases have both English and French versions on them. This is pretty much universal as far as I know, moreso than with cinema showings.

Legally, though, even Quebec does not require any of this for movies, either in cinemas or retail. Source: http://www.rcq.gouv.qc.ca/en/faq.asp#presente